# How can I fix this GStreamer update bug on a fresh install of Kubuntu 23.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, dependencies, gstreamer

I've got a brand new Lenovo Ideapad which I just installed KUbuntu 23.04 onto. However, the package manager isn't updating everything. Specifically three packages, all related to GStreamer, are failing to update.

The specific warning message is:

Package failed to install:
Error while installing package: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstcamerabin.so', which is also in package gstreamer1.0-plugins-good

The advice is to try again later, but if it's attempting to overwrite a package, I'm not sure that that will have any affect.

When I attempt to remove GStreamer and reinstall it from scratch (`sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-plugins-good`), I'm greeted with a list of missing dependencies, and the advice to run `apt --fix-broken install, which wants to download about 700 kB. That's fine, but it's again stopped by the same error in doing so.

Verbatim after --fix-broken:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libbdplus0 libdca0 libdirectfb-1.7-7 libfaad2 liblrdf0 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmpeg2-4 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0
  libmplex2-2.1-0 libneon27 libopenni2-0 libpocketsphinx3 libsidplay1v5 libsphinxbase3 libssh-gcrypt-4
  libvidstab1.1 linux-headers-6.2.0-20 linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic
  linux-modules-6.2.0-20-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-20-generic pocketsphinx-en-us
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
Suggested packages:
  frei0r-plugins libvisual-0.4-plugins
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
102 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,619 kB of archives.
After this operation, 700 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 260527 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1%3a1.22.3-dmo1+deb12u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 (1:1.22.3-dmo1+deb12u1) over (1.22.1-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1%3a1.22.3-dmo1+deb12u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstcamerabin.so', which is also in package gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 1.22.1-1ubuntu1
Preparing to unpack .../libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0_1%3a1.22.3-dmo1+deb12u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64 (1:1.22.3-dmo1+deb12u1) over (1.22.1-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0_1%3a1.22.3-dmo1+deb12u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbasecamerabinsrc-1.0.so.0', which is also in package libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 1.22.1-1ubuntu1
dpkg: regarding .../libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.22.3-dmo1+deb12u2_amd64.deb containing libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64:
 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64 conflicts with libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 (<< 1:1.16.0)
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64 (version 1.22.1-1ubuntu1) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.22.3-dmo1+deb12u2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1%3a1.22.3-dmo1+deb12u1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0_1%3a1.22.3-dmo1+deb12u1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.22.3-dmo1+deb12u2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It's the same deal with other commands, but if anyone needs specifics, I can look it up.

The laptop/graphics tablet works fine, but I would really like to get this resolved, and I'm personally running out of ideas. Can someone give me a pointer on what to do next to resolve this?

The only software I've installed is Krita, Blender 3.6 (by direct download, not through a repo), and OpenToonz via snap. It's a particularly fresh machine, I never put GStreamer on it myself save by installing KUbuntu.

Comment: As a side note, I attempted to install OpenToonz through Flatpak, but it couldn't find the repo, so I went with Snap. My issues only came up after installing updates, and at this point I can't seem to install anything through apt or the software center.

Comment: After taking another look, it appears as though `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0` needs to be greater than 1.22.3, but won't go above 1.22.1-1ubuntu1. Perhaps this is something that just needs to be integrated into the repo before I can continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's finally working, and while it's difficult to be sure, the problem seemed to stem from Snap somehow.

I went ahead and first attempted to uninstall absolutely everything that was causing issues. This quickly became quite a list:

```
sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-x libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer gstreamer1.0-gl libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtk-4-media-gstreamer libqt5multimediagsttools5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins elisa
```

But I reasoned that if a dependency was missing or corrupted, then I wasn't getting full use out of it anyway. However, `phonon` ended up introducing another ourouborous-type unfixable error. So, I plugged in my original LiveUSB, and attempted to, as nondestructively as possible, reinstall KUbuntu.

System files and settings were preserved, including config files. The first thing I did was install all available updates, then I got back to work. Blender was still on there because I just grabbed the binary, as is my custom. Krita needed to be reinstalled, through the Discover Software Center, but remembered all of my settings and my documents, which is great.

I even restarted to be sure, the old GStreamer bug had not come up. So, I went ahead and attempted to install OpenToonz with flatpak, instead of snap. I had to add flathub:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

After that, I could simply install the flatpak packages necessary for OpenToonz:

```
flatpak install flathub io.github.OpenToonz
```

This took a little while, but I now have Blender, OpenToonz, and Krita, all functioning on a properly updating system.

The one major difference is that I installed with Flatpak instead of Snap; what Snap's issue is, I can't be sure.